# how to bring back the claw to initial positon?

Tags: python, pygame

I have to make a game, everything looks good except that I can't make my claw go up after going down to the Y position defined by the cursor. I used ChatGPT to help me but he saying rubbish. I think my code's very bad, I'm a beginner in **PyGame** and I need help.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import time
times = 20000

# initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# create pygam window
screen_width = 467
screen_height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
# Set cursor position and cursor direction variables
cursor_x = 71
cursor_y = 25
cursor_direction = 1
cursor_speed = 3

# Set cursor position and direction variables y
cursor_y_x = 13
cursor_y_y = 196
cursor_y_direction = 1
cursor_y_speed = 1.5
claw_placed_x = False
claw_placed_y = False

# Create the Claw class as a subclass of pygame.sprite.Sprite


class Claw(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, open_image, closed_image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.open_image = open_image
        self.closed_image = closed_image
        self.image = self.open_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.is_open = True
        self.target_y = -200
        self.claw_placed = False
        self.time_to_raise = 3000  # time in milliseconds before raising the claw
        self.time_since_placement = self.time_to_raise
        self.claw_placed = False  # claw placement indicator

    def update(self):
        if self.claw_placed:
            if self.rect.y < self.target_y:
                # Calculate the distance to travel
                distance = self.target_y - self.rect.y
                # Calculate moving speed based on distance

                speed = distance / 10
                # updating
                self.rect.y += speed
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(60)
            else:
                # Claw is on targeted position
                self.time_since_placement += 1  # increment time since last placement
                if self.time_since_placement >= self.time_to_raise:
                    # if the time since placement is greater than or equal to the time to wait, raise the gripper
                    self.target_y = -200
                    self.claw_placed = False
                    self.time_since_placement = 0  # reset counter
        else:
            if self.rect.y > self.target_y:
                # Calculate the distance to travel
                distance = self.rect.y - self.target_y
                # # Calculate moving speed based on distance
                speed = distance / 10
                # updating
                self.rect.y -= speed
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(60)

    def toggle(self):
        self.is_open = not self.is_open
        if self.is_open:
            self.image = self.open_image
        else:
            self.image = self.closed_image
            self.target_y = -200  # Make the Claw going to his initial position
            self.claw_placed = False


# load images
background_image = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
claw_open_image = pygame.image.load("claw_open.png").convert_alpha()
claw_closed_image = pygame.image.load("claw_close.png").convert_alpha()
bkg_front = pygame.image.load("backg.png").convert_alpha()
rod_x = pygame.image.load("rod_x.png").convert_alpha()
rod_y = pygame.image.load("rod_y.png").convert_alpha()

# creete claw object with two state (closed or open)
claw = Claw(claw_open_image, claw_closed_image, 250, -200)

# create pygame window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# main func


def main():
    global cursor_x, cursor_y, cursor_direction, cursor_speed, claw_placed_y, claw_placed_x, times
    global cursor_y_x, cursor_y_y, cursor_y_direction
    # game loop

    def game():
        global cursor_x, cursor_y, cursor_direction, cursor_speed, claw_placed_y, claw_placed_x, running, times
        global cursor_y_x, cursor_y_y, cursor_y_direction, cursor_y_speed

        times = times-1
        # manage events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # Quit game if wndow closed
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not claw_placed_x:
                    # Place the claw on the x axis
                    claw.rect.x = cursor_x - 71
                    claw_placed_x = True
                    cursor_speed = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and claw_placed_x and not claw_placed_y:
                    # Place the claw on the y axis
                    claw.rect.y = cursor_y_y - 443
                    claw_placed_y = True
                    claw.toggle()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    claw.target_y = -200

       # update horizontale position of the cursor
        cursor_x += cursor_direction

        # reverse cursor direction
        if cursor_x < 71 or cursor_x > 384:
            cursor_direction *= -1
        if claw_placed_x == True:
            # update vertical position of the cursor y if the claw isn' placed on y axis
            if not claw_placed_y:

                cursor_y_y += cursor_y_direction*cursor_y_speed

                if cursor_y_y < 196 or cursor_y_y > 474:
                    cursor_y_direction *= -1
                    cursor_y_speed += 0.05
                    if cursor_y_speed > 5:
                        cursor_y_speed = 0.5
        try:
            # display background
            screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
            # display actual position of the claw
            screen.blit(claw.image, (claw.rect.x, claw.rect.y))
            # display claw machine
            screen.blit(bkg_front, (0, 0))
        except pygame.error as e:
            print("Erreur:", e)

        # display x cursor

        if not claw_placed_x:
            screen.blit(rod_x, (8, 30))

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (64, 64, 64),
                             (cursor_x, cursor_y, 10, 20))

        # display y cursor
        if claw_placed_x == True:
            if not claw_placed_y:
                screen.blit(rod_y, (18, 189))

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (64, 64, 64),
                                 (cursor_y_x, cursor_y_y, 20, 10))
        # update window
        pygame.display.update()
        if times <= 0:
            pygame.quit()
    if claw_placed_y:
        claw.update()
    running = True
    while running:

        game()


# call main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to use different methods and different way to solve the problems like chatGPT, youtube, blackbox and google but nothing worked.

I expect to make the claw going back to his initial position (in -200) after going down to the position of the Y cursor.

Nothing worked and either the claw stays up or stays down.(time.sleep or pygame.time didn't work). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts that may help. First:

```
def main():
  ...
  def game():
    ...
  if claw_placed_y:
      claw.update()
  running = True
  while running:
    game()
```

It seems like that `if claw_placed_y:` statement is supposed to be in the "game" method.

Second, you really don't need to have a method within a method for this, see how this is equivalent:

```
def main():
  ...
  if claw_placed_y:
      claw.update()
  running = True
  while running:
    ...
    # This is the contents of that game() #
```

Inside the game method / while loop there is this:

```
  elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not claw_placed_x:
      # Place the claw on the x axis
      claw.rect.x = cursor_x - 71
      claw_placed_x = True
      cursor_speed = 0
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and claw_placed_x and not claw_placed_y:
      # Place the claw on the y axis
      claw.rect.y = cursor_y_y - 443
      claw_placed_y = True
      claw.toggle()
      pygame.display.update()
      claw.target_y = -200
```

There is another condition that isn't handled here, when both claw_placed_x and claw_placed_y are True. Both of these variables are only ever set from False to True in this loop, so once you've hit the space twice they will never change. You have to handle all cases for whatever flow you are trying to make.

Finally, you could add a method in your Claw class, like reset. Keep whatever starting values you want ... call the claw.reset() function whenever you want.

```
class Claw(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, open_image, closed_image, x, y): 
    super().__init__()
    # your other initialization stuff ...
    # could save the starting x and y if we want
    self.startx = x
    self.starty = y

  def reset(self):
    # the new reset method could set values to some static or stored value
    self.rect.x = self.startx
    self.rect.y = self.starty
    self.target_y = -200
```